# vertical carousel cutting off images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, vertical-scrolling

I am currently aiming to implement a vertical carousel, to allow users to navigate through a gallery of thumbanils, the carousel is meant to show 3 items per click however it only shows 2 and a bit.

The link to see it in action is http://mensclothingroom.factoryagency.co.uk/product/lambswool-round-neck-sweater/

Have I implemented it incorrectly I personally think that the plugin is working out the parent containers height incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your js file (`/themes/mcr/resources/javascript/jquery.carousel.min.js`) at this moment your wrapper height is calculated by

```
s.itemHeight * s.steps.count + "px"
```

but `$itemHeight = $item.outerHeight();` and this don't take into account the margin-bottom (`6px`) you inserted for your `<li>` elements: in fact you wrapper is now `252px` height tall (that is `84px * 3`) instead of `266px` so you should change that expression into

`$itemHeight = $item.outerHeight(true);`

this will make the wrapper tall enough `(84 + 6)px * 3 = 270px` to contain entirely three thumbnails but , of course, adjust and tune the height calculation to fit your need.

see http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ for more information